# Eloquent using wrong key for some tables

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Using: Laravel 5.5

I Constructing addresses using some address elements (like: district, area, zip etc) as dropdowns & also some user inputs.

I have 5 address element & one of their schema is:

```
Schema::create('address_districts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('admin_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admins');
        });
```

This is for Districts, & I have another 3 exactly same like this called, `address_thanas`, `address_areas`, `address_building_names` & `address_zips`;

The only exception for the last one is that has `code` instead of `name` on other tables:

```
Schema::create('address_zips', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('admin_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('code'); // Look other table has name here........

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admins');
        });
```

I store constructed addresses on the table called `addresses`

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('district_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('thana_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('area_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('zip_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('building_name_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->string('building');
            $table->integer('floor');
            $table->string('apt')->nullable();
            $table->text('comment')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('district_id')->references('id')->on('address_districts');
            $table->foreign('thana_id')->references('id')->on('address_thanas');
            $table->foreign('area_id')->references('id')->on('address_areas');
            $table->foreign('zip_id')->references('id')->on('address_zips');
            $table->foreign('building_name_id')->references('id')->on('address_building_names');
        });
```

In `Address` Model I've defined relationships like:

```
public function district() {

        return $this->belongsTo(AddressDistrict::class, 'district_id');
    }

    public function thana() {

        return $this->belongsTo(AddressThana::class, 'thana_id');
    }

    public function area() {

        return $this->belongsTo(AddressArea::class, 'area_id');
    }

    public function building_name() {

        return $this->belongsTo(AddressBuildingName::class, 'building_name_id');
    }

    public function zip() {

        return $this->belongsTo(AddressZip::class, 'zip_id', 'id');
    }
```

Then when I try to create a new address using `Address::create($data)`
I get error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `address_zips` where `name` = 2)
```

Here we can see that it is comparing the key `name` instead of `id`

I noticed that this is not reporting that the data cannot be inserted or something like that, it fails to count related model & for that aborts insertion of data

Why is that? 
But the strange thing is I can retrieve data by (inserted a row manually into db for testing to see if that can retrieve data)

```
$addresses = Address::orderByDesc('created_at')->get();
//loop as $address
$address->district->name
$address->zip->code
...
```

& this works perfect

When I am creating a new record I need that query look like:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `address_zips` where `id` = 2
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks for reading this long question.

Comment: Do you change your primary key column instead of default id?

Comment: One the other hand you table does not contain any name column but may be $data contain name attribute. Check your $data carefully.

Comment: no, should i? I want use default 'id' if that's not a problem & 

$data does not contain 'name', it contains, 'zip_id' in the zip field & that's used as foreign key as you can see it it the question 'addresses' table & 'Address' model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `$data` array. Probably you copied a form with an input `name`, you need to rename it to `code` in order to save the values automatically.

Alternatively, you can set the input manually

```
$address = new Address();
$address->code = request('name');
$address->save();
```

Comment: Thank you for you'r answer, No actually that not the case, I wrote 'name' instead of 'code' in the validation rules, when using 'exists', & for this laravel tried to check if theres anything in table using the 'name', btw, much appreciated

Comment: I accepted this answer because, most likely this is what can be the problem /solution & someone can find this helpful